# Chinese lettes not read properly using Java Mail API

Tags: java, api, email

I am having an email listener which reads mail from gmail. When I send a mail from Outlook client which contains chinese character,  the encoding is set to gb2312, which causes improper result in part.getContent() in Java mail api .

If encoding from client is set to Chinese Big5 program works properly but we can't change the encoding in Outlook Client . Is there a way to read from Java Mail API but setting the content type or any alternate approach to get the proper content??????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://community.oracle.com/message/5440489#5440489

Used GBK charset to read the file for all GB2312 file since gb2312 is a subset of GBK.

Answer (score 0):

The following then should work with a bit of luck:

```
String content = mail. ...

// The bytes as sent, and then interpreted as gb2312:
byte[] bytes = content.getBytes("gb2312");

// Now correctly interprete the bytes as Big5:
content = new String(bytes, "Big5");
```

Comment: This doesn't works...My actual input:地址及電話均正確。, Input after doing new String(bytes,"Big5") - 華硊摯??歙淏?

Comment: Sorry for the made effort at your side. I hope you could follow my idea.

Comment: Yeah I tried that... from part.getContent() I wrote the same code which u hav specified. but still junk characters are shown

Comment: got the solution... we should use GBK instead of gb2312.